# jqPagination : has a undefined function when using on asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, paging, jqpagination

Hello i am using jqPagination for paging on my asp.net using master and slave forms. When I placed the same code as the tutorial did, I encountered a typeError: an undefined is not a function $(...).jqPagination(...). I think the jqPagination wasn't defined.

I have imported the jsPaingation files and the code pretty much the same. I have searched on stackoverflow and view one of the link which provided a link :[Link to `jsFiddle` demo](http://jsfiddle.net/beneverard/2HLZF/) also have this problem..

Does anyone know why is that? Is there something i did wrong

Comment: This issue with that jsFiddle is because github doesn't present the file as a script but as a plain file. In this similar instance it works fine http://jsfiddle.net/GKHmA/. Check to make sure jqPagination is loaded correctly.

Comment: The script file did load... some how the code inside didn't work... I tried other pager script but have the same problem... Must be something within the asp.net form causing it somehow...